# How to solve the following system of $4$ nonlinear equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, computer-algebra-systems

How to solve this equation system?

$$\frac{-1}{x_1^{2} x_2 x_3} +y(x_2+2x_3) = 0, $$

$$x_3- \frac{1}{x_1 x_2^{2} x_3} + y x_1 = 0, $$

$$x_2 - \frac{1}{x_1 x_2 x_3^{2}} + 2yx_1 = 0, $$

$$x_1 x_2 + x_1 x_3 = 4 $$

where $x_1,x_2,x_3,y \neq 0$.

I have tried, but I can't get something. It seems unclear how to express one variable in terms of the others.

Comment: This isn’t linear

Comment: Small advices: if the equations are numbered (1) to (4), begin by simplifying (1) by using (4) in it, and set $z=yx_1$ which will simplify further treatments.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "mathematical programming". You have plainly to solve a (non linear) system of 4 equations with 4 unknowns, that can, besides, have $0$, $1,2$... or an infinity of solutions.

Comment: I wrote mathematical programming because this is part of problem from mathematical programming.

Comment: please add more information to the words "mathematical programming". are ambigous words that can be this [Mathematical programming wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization), Mathematical Programming Language like MATLAB or [Wolfram Mathematica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_Mathematica).

Comment: I think on mathematical optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are satisfied with a computational solution then one may consider the variety $V \subset \mathbb{A}^4_{x_1, x_2, x_3, y}$ given by

\begin{align*}
x_1^2 x_2^2 x_3 y + 2 x_1^2 x_2 x_3^2 y - 1 = 0 \\
x_1^2 x_2^2 x_3 y + x_1 x_2^2 x_3^2 - 1 =0\\
2 x_1^2 x_2 x_3^2 y + x_1 x_2^2 x_3^2 - 1 =0\\
x_1 x_2 + x_1 x_3 - 4 =0
\end{align*}
these are the numerators of your rational functions - i.e., this condition holds when $x_1,x_2,x_3,y \neq 0$ if and only if your condition holds.

The variety $V$ has dimension $0$ and (over $\mathbb{Q}$) has exactly one irreducible component. However it has no rational points i.e., your original equation has no solution in $\mathbb{Q}$.

However, let $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ be a root of $f(x) = x^4 - 4x^2 - 12x +4$. Then over $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ (and indeed over $\mathbb{C}$) there are exactly $4$ solutions to the original system, namely
\begin{align*}
(x_1, x_2, x_3, y) = \left( \frac{4\alpha^2 - 8}{9}, \frac{\alpha^3 - 2\alpha - 12}{4}, \frac{\alpha^3 - 2\alpha - 12}{8}, \frac{9\alpha^3 + 3\alpha^2 - 36\alpha - 114}{64} \right)
\end{align*}
and its Galois conjugates (i.e., replace $\alpha$ by the other $3$ roots of $f(x)$).

All of these claims were checked with Magma as follows:

```
F := Rationals();  // Replace this with the field you care about.
A<x1,x2,x3,y> := AffineSpace(F,  4);

f1 := Numerator( (-1)/(x1^2*x2*x3) + y*(x2 + 2x3));
f2 := Numerator( x3 - 1/(x1*x2^2*x3) + y*x1);
f3 := Numerator( x2 - 1/(x1*x2*x3^2) + 2*y*x1);
f4 := x1*x2 + x1*x3 - 4;

C := Cluster(A, [f1,f2,f3,f4]);

P<a> := PolynomialRing(F);
K<a> := quo<P | (a^4 - 4*a^2 - 12*a+ 4)>;

Degree(C) eq 4;
Points(C, K);
```

Comment: I'm sorry. Fourth condition is $x_1x_2+x_1x_3=4$.

Comment: @Broj1 ok, i have reanswered with this condition. Over $\mathbb{C}$ there should be $4$ solutions

Comment: I know solution $(2,1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4})$, but I can't come to it. Minimize $x_2x_3+\frac{1}{x_1x_2x_3}$ with subject to $x_1x_2+x_1x_3\leq 4, x_1,x_2,x_3\gt 0$ is actually problem where I am solving that system.

Comment: The first equation does not vanish at $(2,1,1/2, 1/4)$.

Comment: Maybe if $x_1x_2+x_1x_3\leq 4$ we change with $x_1x_2+2x_1x_3\leq 4$?

Comment: @Broj1 the question you ask in your most recent comment will require very different techniques to answer. I have answered both your original question and your corrected question giving exact solutions. If you wish to change your question I suggest you post a new question under accurate tags. Adding context to your question is very important. In particular, why are you interested in this problem and what is your background? Are you looking for all solutions? Exact solutions? Approximate solutions? Real solutions? Complex solutions? Integer solutions?

Comment: Only real solutions.

Comment: @Broj1 I suggest you upvote the solution of Mummy the turkey which is very valuable.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions are:

$y=\frac{3^{5/3}}{2^{16/3}}$,

$x_{1}=\frac{2^{11/3}}{3^{4/3}}$,

$x_{2}=\frac{3^{1/3}}{2^{2/3}}$,

$x_{3}=\frac{3^{1/3}}{2^{5/3}}$.

From the first three equations we write the value of the variable y as a function of $x_{1}$, $x_{2}$ and $x_{3}$:

$y=\frac{1}{x_{1}^2x_{2} x_{3}(x_{2}+2x_{3})}=\frac{1-x_{1} x_{2}^{2} x_{3}^{2}}{ x_{1}^2 x_{2}^{2} x_{3}}=\frac{1-x_{1} x_{2}^{2} x_{3}^{2}}{2 x_{1}^{2} x_{2}  x_{3}^{2}}$,

From the last equality we derive:

$x_{2}=2x_{3}$.

Consequently

$y=\frac{1}{x_{1}^{2}(2x_{3}) x_{3}(2x_{3}+2x_{3}}=\frac{1}{8x_{1}^{2} x_{3}^{3}}$.

From the second equation we derive:

$x_{1}=\frac{1}{8x_{3}^{4}}$,

and finally from the fourth equation we get:

$\frac{1}{8x_{3}^{4}}(2x_{3}+x_{3})=4$,

$\frac{3}{8x_{3}^3}=4$,

$x_{3}=\frac{6^{1/3}}{4}$.

Backwards we can calculate the values of the other unknowns.

Comment: The actual values are one thing, the way to reach them is another - more important - thing. Could you give some information about the way you have obtained them ?